# How to extract the content of a custome tag and replace with valid tag with data from cuctom tag using php

Tags: php, html, iframe

Please how do i use custome tags and replace the content with valid html tag.
`[video]thelinktothevideo[/video]` then replace with valid youtube video.
thanks for your help. i am using php

Answer (score 0):

The most straight way is to use regular expression replace.

```
$output = preg_replace('!\[video\](.*?)\[\/video\]!i', '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $input);
```

You need to modify the code to your need as you need to convert a link to its embed link.

Comment: thanks let me try it. if i first strip tag will the custom tag be stript off?

Comment: this is perfect. i can now build my custom post comment field

Comment: @TrustOkoroego strip_tags only strip HTML tags. These are ubb tags.